# Wrong layout of tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I create a level an array of int's. This is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Level1 : MonoBehaviour 
{
    int[][] level = new int[][]
    {
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
        new int[] { 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16}
    };
    public Transform tile00;
public Transform tile16;
public Transform tile38;

int rows = 12;
int cols = 32;

void Start () 
{

    BuildLevel ();
}

void BuildLevel(){
    int i, j;

    GameObject dynamicParent = GameObject.Find ("DynamicObjects");
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            Transform toCreate = null;
            Debug.Log (i + "  ,  " + j + "   " + level[i][j]);
            if (level[i][j] == 0)
                toCreate = tile00;
            if (level[i][j] == 83)
                toCreate = tile38;;
            if (level[i][j] == 16)
                toCreate = tile16;

            Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(16-j, 6-i, 0);
            Transform newObject = Instantiate(toCreate, v3, Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
            newObject.parent = dynamicParent.transform;
        }
    }
}
  }
```

The output screen is like that:

[image]

The tiles are 50 X 50. I changed the dimensions of tiles, I changed the positions on X and Y. I tried everything but I found no solution.Could you give me an ideea, please ?

For the horizontal tiles the layout I want to obtain is (the image is processed with paint) :

[image]

Comment: Uh...it's not entirely clear at the moment what you want your code to do - could you clarify how you expected your scene to look after running your code? Otherwise we're just left guessing about what might be wrong here.

Comment: Tried everything for what solution? You don't even specify what layout you want.

Comment: @Serlite - I posted an image for the layout I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely answer is because of this line

```
Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(16-j, 6-i, 0);
```

You say that your images are 50 x 50 px each. Assuming that you haven't changed the pixels to units property of your sprite, this would make each of these image occupy a space of 0.5 Unity units on both the X & Y axes.

Now, in your calculation, here's what is happening.

---

Iteration 1 - (i = 0, j = 0). Position = Vector3(16, 6, 0)
Iteration 2 - (i = 0, j = 1). Position = Vector3(15, 6, 0)
...

Iteration 33 -(i = 1, j = 0). Position = Vector3(16, 5, 0)

---

Now, the difference in the X values between *Iteration 1 & Iteration 2* is 1 Unity unit. We've already established earlier that these Sprites will occupy only 0.5 Unity unit due to their size. 
Same thing along the Y axis for *Iteration 1 & Iteration 33*. A difference of 1 unit, with each image occupying only 0.5 units.

So, either change the image to be 100 x 100 px, or change the pixels to units

Comment: Yes. Tou're right. I change the pixels to unit 50 px and is OK. Thanks